# strange behavior in tuple extraction

Tags: python, tuples

Using python 3.4 I faced some problem with a tuple extraction.

```
a = ([[], [{'blablabla1'},{'blablabla2'}]], '/path/to/folder/example/4.pdf') 
for elem1,elem2 in a:
    print (elem1,'\n',elem2)
```

as a result of that code snippet I always have my `elem1` is equal  to `[ ]` and `elem2` is equal to `[{'blablabla1'},{'blablabla2'}]`.

All I want it's `elem1` stores `[ [ ], [ {bla1},{bla2}] ]` and `elem2` stores `'path/to/folder/...'` string.

Please lead me out of the dark of using a tuple unpacking (wrong?).

Comment: as it always have two elems in my list i tried next: for elem1,elem2 in a[0],a[1] but had same result

Comment: it is because you are looping over tuple's value that is one element at atime so you get that

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop; just assign directly:

```
elem1, elem2 = a
print(elem1, '\n' ,elem2)
```

Since all you want to do is put a newline between them, you could just loop over your tuple and print the 2 elements separately:

```
for elem in a:
    print(elem)
```